# Tree fern burned fronds, browning leaves? (Pictures)

Tags: trees, diagnosis, ferns

I have bought a tree fern and have put it in a pot about a month ago. Since then it has been having black edges around the leaves and browning. It is spring and there are new shoots growing. I'm keeping it in a sheltered place and giving it plenty of water, used traditional potting mix. What's going wrong? Is this a natural part of its cycle or am I killing the poor fella :(

Gets about 4 hours filtered sunlight in the morning then shade the rest of the day. I water about once week or less since it's been raining on and off.

[image: Blackening edges of leaves]

[image: browning leaves]

[image: general browning of the leaves]

Comment: How much sun does it get, especially in the middle of the day? How often exactly do you water?